# Multi touch and Adobe AIR for Mobile

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, touch

I am developing a game for Android using Adobe AIR 3.0, also i am using Samsung Galaxy S2 to test my game, and is running pretty well with decent 30 fps.

to control the game-play, i am using virtual joystick and some button on screen (e.g. to throw weapon, jump etc).

however it seems that multitouch is not working fine, if i press one button and and in the same time if i down another button. first one stops working.

here is the code snippet which defines multitouch behavior -

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
```

for jump button, virtual joystick etc -  i am using TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN event.
please let me know what is wrong with touch event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://flex.org/tour-de-mobile-flex/ is worth checking out. It has been helpful to me.

From the MultiTouch.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

  <fx:Script>
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import spark.components.Label;

    private var circles:Object = new Object();
  </fx:Script>

  <fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Component className="Circle">
      <s:Ellipse width="140" height="140">
        <s:fill>
          <s:SolidColor color="#ff0000"/>
        </s:fill>
      </s:Ellipse>
    </fx:Component>
  </fx:Declarations>

  <s:creationComplete>
      Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

      if (Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents)
      {
        l.text = "maxTouchPoints = " + Multitouch.maxTouchPoints;

        addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, function(event:TouchEvent):void {
          var c:Circle = new Circle();
          c.x = event.localX - 70;
          c.y = event.localY - 70;
          addElement(c);
          circles[event.touchPointID] = c;
        });
        addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, function(event:TouchEvent):void {
          if (circles[event.touchPointID] != null)
          {
            circles[event.touchPointID].x = event.localX - 70;
            circles[event.touchPointID].y = event.localY - 70;
          }
        });
        addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, function(event:TouchEvent):void {
          if (circles[event.touchPointID] != null)
          {
            removeElement(circles[event.touchPointID]);
            delete circles[event.touchPointID];
          }
        });
        addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_OUT, function(event:TouchEvent):void {
          if (circles[event.touchPointID] != null)
          {
            removeElement(circles[event.touchPointID]);
            delete circles[event.touchPointID];
          }
        });
      }
      else
      {
        l.text = "MultiTouch is not supported on this device";
      }
  </s:creationComplete>

  <s:Label id="l" paddingTop="10"/>

</s:Group>
```

Comment: thanks for the point, multitouch is working fine for me (and my test device samsung galaxy s2 too).-

here is a more detail on how multitouchs stops working - 
when i press my joystick and then jump button, my joystick still works fine, but in case of if i press jump button, and then try to move via joystick, joystick doesn't receives multitouch, or touch_begin events.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a `touchPointID` is assigned to every touch event, and this `touchPointID` will be consistent through it's own TOUCH_BEGIN, TOUCH_MOVE, and TOUCH_END.  If you end up cancelling the touch event based on the wrong touch point, the results may never occur.  See the [Adobe tuts dealing with `touchPointID`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1ca064e08d7aa93023c59dfc1257b16a3d6-7ffe.html#WSedf167eee00ebe75-2fd6c0b41270ca3ed61-8000).

However, you will have to post your code to know what is really happening.

Comment: still this issue is not resolved, is it something like - we cannot add more than one eventListeners for TOUCH_BEGINE , TOUCH_MOVE, TOUCH_END etc, i am using 3 eventListener's, once for my joystick, 2nd for jump button, and third for jump button.

I am not sure about the root cause of this multitouch failure.
any input s greatly appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: @TryTryAgain ok, let me break down and figure out - 

my other control (i.e.) jump button, pause button & jump button has TOUCH_TAP event listener(since i need to fire these events exactly in the way mouse click works), while my virtual joystick button has TOUCH_BEGIN and TOUCH_END event handlers. i suspect if TOUCH_TAP is breaking the multitouch,

Comment: You will have to post the code to test . . . I do not have enough experience to know a solution off the top of my head.